# spring cloud stream starter stream kafka consumer SSL configuration

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Spring cloud stream starter kafka is not loading the configuration when it is wiring the consumer. The following is configuration that I see in my console when I ran it in debug mode:

```
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
```

I have the following configuration part of bootstrap yml file

```
    spring:
     cloud:
      stream:
       bindings:
         <binding configuration>
       kafka:
        binder:
         autoCreateTopics: false
         brokers: <list of kafka brokers>
         defaultBrokerPort: <default port>
        configuration:
         security:
          protocol: SSL
         ssl:
          truststore:
           location: <path to cliend truststore jks>
           password: <password>
           type: JKS
          keystore:
           location: <path to cliend keystore jks>
           password: <password>
           type: JKS
          key:
           password: <password>
          enabled:
           protocols: TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
```

Can anyone let me know if I am configuring it correctly? I am able to successfully post messages to the topic using spring-kafka producer. I want to make sure that I did it correctly before I consider writing a consumer also in spring kafka.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can put security and protocol (for example) are at two levels in the sample yaml you provided since Kafka is looking for properties like `security.protocol`, `ssl.truststore.location` etc. So, when you create the yaml file, provide all the security related kafka properties at the same level in the hierarchy. Otherwise, spring puts them as key/value pairs.

```
spring:
     cloud:
      stream:
       bindings:
         <binding configuration>
       kafka:
        binder:
         autoCreateTopics: false
         brokers: <list of kafka brokers>
         defaultBrokerPort: <default port>
        configuration:
         security.protocol: SSL
         ssl.truststore.location: <path to cliend truststore jks>
         ssl.truststore.password: <password>
         ssl.truststore.type: JKS
...
```

Comment: I tried setting the properties as key/value pair and I am seeing the same behavior

Answer (score 1):

Configuration is loading after changing it to how it is reported in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/129

Thanks to stackoverflow for recommending the post referring to the above git issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I also have undergone through the same problem. Unfortunately sobychacko's answer didn't work for me. Though the approach is correct, I assume the mistake is in the indentation where the "configuration" prop is placed.

Refer to 3.4.1 section in this link - https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/

It worked for me when I placed the "configuration" prop in the same column as 
spring.cloud.stream.binder.brokers i.e.

```
spring:   
  cloud:
    stream:
      binder:
        brokers:
        configuration:
         security:
          protocol: SSL
         ssl:
          truststore:
           location: <path to cliend truststore jks>
           password: <password>
           type: JKS
          keystore:
           location: <path to cliend keystore jks>
           password: <password>
           type: JKS
          key:
           password: <password>
          enabled:
           protocols: TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
```

With this I can see the corresponding fields filled in the log.